# JPQL Constructor Expressions, how to eagerly fetch the main entity in 'select new'

Tags: sql, hibernate, select, jpa

The original query I have is somewhat complex, but what I'm trying to do is obtain the entity AlertCondition plus some additional fields.

```
    + "  SELECT new org.rhq.core.domain.alert.composite.AlertConditionEventCategoryComposite " //
    + "       ( " //
    + "         ac, " //
    + "         res.id " //
    + "       ) " //
    + "    FROM AlertCondition AS ac FETCH ALL PROPERTIES " //
    + "    JOIN ac.alertDefinition ad " //
    + "    JOIN ad.resource res " //
    + "   WHERE " + AlertCondition.RECOVERY_CONDITIONAL_EXPRESSION //
    + "     AND ( res.agent.id = :agentId OR :agentId IS NULL ) " //
    + "     AND ad.enabled = TRUE " //
    + "     AND ad.deleted = FALSE " //
    + "     AND ac.category = 'EVENT' " //
    + "ORDER BY ac.id"), //
```

The problem is *Hibernate* only selects the ID of AlertCondition, so when accessing this object, this ends up requiring N+1 selects whereas I would like to do only 1.

The select is only fetching the ID column, according to debug:

```
select alertcondi0_.ID as col_0_0_, alertdefin1_.ID as col_1_0_, resource2_.ID as col_2_0_
```

What I'm trying to get back are all the fields of *AlertCondition.

I can't find any way to do this under *Hibernate*. `JOIN FETCH` doesn't really work here either.

The alternative is to select every column of the table, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: What's your query call for this select? What's the content of your AlertCondition entity?

Comment: Hi, yes, since you're using a custom constructor expression, we need to see that there is matching constructor in your AlertCondition entity

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue.
I don't know how to let hibernate fetch `ac.*` neither.

But I found a workaround.

```
@Query("select ac, xxx, zzz")
List<Object[]> fetchRecords()

//
Constructor<?> constructor = AlertConditionEventCategoryComposite.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
List<AlertConditionEventCategoryComposite> composites = fetchRecords.stream().map(constructor::newInstance).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can tell hibernate to fetch an ad with:

```
JOIN FETCH ac.alertDefinition ad
```